# Figuring out addresses in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, memory-address

I'm trying to learn how to figure out addresses in C. For the code below, assuming it's compiled on a 32-bit little endian machine.

```
struct {
    int n;
    char c;
} A[10][10];
```

Say the address of A[0][0] is 1000(decimal), what would the address of A[3][7] be? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Surely you mean `&A[0][0]`...

Comment: You should try that in a real program. Details are compiler, operating system, ABI, and instruction set specific. You may need to use `offsetof` and `__alignof__` and `sizeof` with GCC.

Comment: Why not compile it, print the addresses and then figure out how the compiler laid things out?

Comment: http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~skiena/214/lectures/lect20/lect20.html this can make you understand I hope

Comment: I'm more interested in finding out addresses on a conceptual level, the program above is more just a concrete example of what I'm trying to learn.

Comment: Most likely, the struct would be padded to nearest type boundary of the largest used data type. Here it is int, so sizeof of one entry of A would be 8 bytes. i.e. sizeof(A[0][0]) would be 8. Do the math from the starting address.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C is *row-major ordered*, which means that the left-most index is computed first. Thus:

```
&A[3] == 1000 + (3 * 10 * sizeof(your_struct))
```

To find the column, we just add the remaining index:

```
&A[3][7] == 1000 + (3 * 10 * sizeof(your_struct)) + (7 * sizeof(your_struct))
```

---

Note that this has nothing to do with big-endian vs little-endian architecture. That's just the location of bytes within a word, whereas you want the location of structs within an array.

Also, `sizeof(your_struct)` isn't guaranteed to be `sizeof(n) + sizeof(c)` because the compiler could pad your struct.

Lastly, the *32-bit* nature of your machine means that the size of the memory-address register is 32 bits. (Or to put it another way, `sizeof(void*)==32`). It's an indication of how much memory your processor can actually assign an address to. That is a separate issue from the size of data types in C.

Answer (score 2):

This is not dependent on the C language standard but on the compiler, compiler version and OS you are using/targeting.

The only way to get a result for your specific case will be to manually test.

Answer (score 1):

Array notation is simply a shorthand for calculating the address of an element and dereferencing it, like so:

```
int a[5][15];
Address of a[3][7]: &a + 3 * 15 * sizeof(int) + 7 * sizeof(int)
```

This is why you can't use an n-dimensional array without knowing all but the last dimension - the compiler wouldn't know what offset to add to it, in order to calculate the address.

In this case matters are complicated by the fact that you're using a struct. There is the problem of alignment, where structs are padded by the compiler to align to word boundaries. In this case, since the struct itself takes 5 bytes and the next word boundary would be at 8 bytes, the compiler is likely to add 3 unused bytes to the struct to make up the difference. (There are performance advantages to doing so.) Of course, this is not guaranteed at all, and you can manually specify how the compiler should handle such situations.

**Note:** As others have stated this is very dependent on the system and the compiler, so do not take any of this as gospel - try it for yourself to be absolutely sure what the results will be in your case.

Comment: You are correct, of course - for some reason I was thinking column-major. Thanks, I'll update now.

Answer (score 1):

This is for sure compiler and system dependent. But no need to guess. You can simply compile and try

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct {
        int n;
        char c;
    } A[10][10];

    printf("%08x\n", &A[0][0]);
    printf("%08x\n", &A[0][1]);
    printf("%08x\n", &A[1][0]);
    ...
    printf("%08x\n", &A[3][7]);

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It fully dependent upon the system and not on language .

Also the all 2-D , 3-D and so on arrays are actually allocated in sequential manner,Because memory is sequential `(0X00000000 to 0xFFFFFFFF)`there is no such 2-D memory or so .

It's completely dependent on the system that how memory is allocated whether it's `row` major or `column` major

The formula for row major :

```
&A[3][7] == &A[0][0] + (3 * 10 * sizeof(struct s)) + (7 * sizeof(struct s))
```

for column major :

```
&A[3][7] == &A[0][0] + (7 * 10 * sizeof(struct s)) + (3 * sizeof(struct s))
```

Also compiler optimize it by structure padding to faster access by CPU.

So for one object of structure size would be `8` rather than `5` (if int is of size 4 bytes)